# Bitcoin Node API for sendfrom method is not working?

Tags: bitcoind

Bitcoin node api sendfrom method(bitcoin-cli sendfrom "fromaddress" "toaddress" amount) is working fine in command prompt but while creating api in postman it is asking "A wallet passphrase is needed and has not been set".Please find the screenshots below for that.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
bitcoinapi.setWalletPassphrase(passphrase);
```

This must be run before running the API. The wallet must have a password.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.